# Php IP range if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, ip

I want to check in php if a I.P address appears in a specified range and if it does show webform, if not false then do nothing.

here is example of what i am thinking:

```
<?php 
function in_ip_range($ip_one, $ip_two=false){ 
    if($ip_two===false){ 
        if($ip_one==$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){ 
            $ip=true; 
        }else{ 
            $ip=false; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        if(ip2long($ip_one)<=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && ip2long($ip_two)>=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){ 
            $ip=true; 
        }else{ 
            $ip=false; 
        } 
    } 
    return $ip; 
} 
//usage 
echo in_ip_range('192.168.0.0','192.168.1.254'); 
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: show us script/code with what we can do something for you.

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(preg_match("/192\.168\.[0|1]\.\d+/", $ip)){
     echo "form";
}else{
     echo "no form";
}
```

I now see that you do not want to allow ....255? correct?
in that case you need this regex:
`"/192\.168\.[0|1]\.([0|1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])/"`

Comment: Thank you @Andreas very helpful!

Comment: @CarlLewis no problem. Do you understand the code? Understanding a code is in my opinion valued higher than a short code.

Comment: @CarlLewis sorry. I made an error with the pattern for 0-254. It does not accept 0-99. But this pattern does: `192\.168\.[0|1]\.([0|1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|25[0-4]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9])$`